# Paint is drawing under the line instead of on top of it - Java

Tags: java

To get a better understanding, I suggest running the program, but basically every time I draw a line, the new line is going under the old line instead of on top of it. I'm sure it's just some minor logic error, but any suggestions on how to fix something like this would be great. The code is below, it will compile and is executable. I have set the erase button to white on a black background so you can see what is happening. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimplePaint extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton action = new JButton();
    JButton red = new JButton();
    JButton blue = new JButton();
    JButton yellow = new JButton();
    Color initial = Color.MAGENTA;
    JButton thin = new JButton();
    JButton medium = new JButton();
    JButton thick = new JButton();
    Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3);
    private static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    JButton erase = new JButton();
    JButton drawing = new JButton();
    Point start = null;
    Point end = null;
    Line2D draw = new Line2D.Float();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private class Segment {
        private final List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        private final Color color = initial;
        private final Stroke stroke = SimplePaint.this.stroke;
    }

    private final List<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();

    public SimplePaint() {
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(450, 450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        design();

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                segments.add(0, new Segment());
            }
       });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                segments.get(0).points.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                points.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });

        blue.addActionListener(this);
        red.addActionListener(this);
        yellow.addActionListener(this);
        thin.addActionListener(this);
        medium.addActionListener(this);
        thick.addActionListener(this);
        erase.addActionListener(this);
        drawing.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void design() {
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        blue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
        panel.add(blue);

        red.setBackground(Color.RED);
        red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
        panel.add(red);

        yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        yellow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
        panel.add(yellow);

        thin.setText("Thin");
        panel.add(thin);

        medium.setText("Medium");
        panel.add(medium);

        thick.setText("Thick");
        panel.add(thick);

        erase.setText("Erase");
        panel.add(erase);

        drawing.setText("Draw");
        panel.add(drawing);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == blue){
            initial = Color.BLUE;
        }else if(e.getSource() == red){
            initial = Color.RED;
        }else if(e.getSource() == yellow){
            initial = Color.YELLOW;
        }else if(e.getSource() == thin){
            stroke = new BasicStroke(1);
        }else if(e.getSource() == medium){
            stroke = new BasicStroke(5);
        }else if(e.getSource() == thick){
            stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
        }else if(e.getSource() == erase){
            initial = Color.WHITE;
            stroke = new BasicStroke(15);
        }

        //repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        int x1, y1, x2, y2;

        for (Segment segment : segments) {
            g2.setColor(segment.color);
            g2.setStroke(segment.stroke);

            for (int p = 0; p < segment.points.size() - 1; p++) {
                x1 = segment.points.get(p).x;
                y1 = segment.points.get(p).y;
                x2 = segment.points.get(p + 1).x;
                y2 = segment.points.get(p + 1).y;
                g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);


            }

        }
        g2.dispose();

    }  

    public static void main(String []args){
        SimplePaint s = new SimplePaint();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not call dispose() on a Graphics or Graphics2D object which you did create.  That Graphics object belongs to the painting system.

Comment: When I comment out dispose, the program still runs but it does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `g2.drawLine` will overwrite anything already painted into your graphics context.  You're iterating over `segments` in-order, so whatever segment is first in the list will be drawn first, with everything that follows being drawn over it.  When you create a new `Segment`, you're inserting it into your list via `Segments.add(0, newSegment)`, which puts the newest segment at the front of the list - meaning your list has the segments arranged from newest to oldest.  To fix this, you can either iterate over your list in the reverse order, or change your segment-painting code so that new segments get added at the end of the list, instead of the front of it.

Comment: According to what you have said, I am sure I just need to change the line "Segments.add(0, newSegment());", but what do I change that to?

Comment: `segments.add(new Segment())` would do, though you'll also have to change your `MouseMotionListener` to access the new value at the end of the list.

Comment: segments.add(new Segment()); was one of the things I tried. I wasn't able to get it to work but I wasn't aware I also needed to change the MouseMotionListener. I am still not sure how to do this. I am trying Collections.reverse(Segments), but that does not take care of the first element, only the ones after that.

Comment: If you're still having issues - `segments.add(new Segment())` puts your new segment at the end of the list; you'd want to change the listener to do something like `segments.get(segments.size() - 1).points.add(stuff)`; the `get(size-1)` gets you the last element in the list.